# Are nested catches within promises required?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, bluebird

We would like to reduce the number of catch blocks inside our promises. If we remove the nested catches, will exceptions bubble up to the parent catch?

```
temporaryUserModel.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    .then(tempUser => {
        if (tempUser) {
            temporaryUserModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: tempUser.toJSON()._id}, user)
                .then((doc) => {
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        status: 'Success',
                        data: {url: planOpted.chargifySignupUrl}
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => error(err, res));
        } else {
            temporaryUserModel(user).save()
                .then((doc) => {
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        status: 'Success',
                        data: {url: planOpted.chargifySignupUrl}
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => error(err, res));
        }
    })
    .catch(err => error(err, res));
```

We'd like to remove the two nested catches and keep only the catch at the bottom. Is this ok?

Comment: You haven't said *why* you want to remove the inner catches, but I suggest looking here-- > http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html and here --> http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

Comment: you need to return your inner promises, then you can bubble up your exceptions

Comment: rejected promises and thus `.catch()` will bubble up the promise chain if and only if you are returning the inner promises from then `.then()` handler which you are not.  That's the only way the inner promises are attached to the outer chain.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, they won't. They only bubble up to the result promise if you *chain* your promises, for which you need to `return` the inner promises created by the callbacks. Otherwise the outer promise cannot wait for them and will not know when/how they resolve (whether they fulfill or reject).

```
temporaryUserModel.findOne({email: req.body.email}).then(tempUser => {
    if (tempUser) {
        return temporaryUserModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: tempUser.toJSON()._id}, user);
//      ^^^^^^
    } else {
        return temporaryUserModel(user).save();
//      ^^^^^^
    }
}).then((doc) => {
// no need to duplicate this code when you chain anyway
    return res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Success',
        data: {url: planOpted.chargifySignupUrl}
    });
}).catch(err => error(err, res));
```

Comment: Would this work? return temporaryUserModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: tempUser.toJSON()._id}, user).then(()=>{console.log(1)});  Meaning... will it still work if I return it and the "then" is on the end?

Comment: Yes, `,then(…)` returns a promise which you also can `return` from inside the callback. However notice that if you only `console.log`, the fulfillment value will become `undefined`.

Answer (score 10):

You can extract some of the logic into separate functions, and `return` the inner promises to bubble up any exceptions to the promise chain:

```
temporaryUserModel.findOne({email: req.body.email})
  .then(updateTempUser)
  .then(formatResponse)
  .catch(err => error(err, res));

function updateTempUser(tempUser) {
  if (tempUser) {
    return temporaryUserModel.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: tempUser.toJSON()._id
    }, user);
  } else {
    return temporaryUserModel(user).save()
  }
}

function formatResponse(doc) {
  return res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Success',
    data: {url: planOpted.chargifySignupUrl}
  });
}
```