# Are nested catches within promises required if then is used?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I think I got the idea of `Promise`, `then` and `catch` as well as nesting promises as shown in [Are nested catches within promises required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336812/are-nested-catches-within-promises-required). However, if I'm nesting promises and want to avoid inner `catch`s by returning the inner promise, then I'm having trouble to get the following not to crash because of the `Error` thrown in `promise2`:

```
function promise1(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    return promise2().then(promise2Result => {
      if(promise2Result !== "") {
        resolve("The value is "+promise2Result);
      }else {
        reject(new Error("promise2.then error"));
      }
    })
  });
}

function promise2(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    throw new Error("promise2 error");
  });
}
```

Chrome shows me an `Unhandled Rejection (Error): promise2 error` of the `yarn` development server started with `yarn run start`. It points to the `Error` thrown in `promise2`. Firefox debugger jumps to a random line outside of my code and displays nothing.

If I add a `catch` after `promise2().then(...)` the `Error` is caught.

How can I avoid the inner `catch`? And catch the `Error` from `promise2` e.g. in a `catch` in

```
promise1()
  .then(value => alert(value))
  .catch(err => alert("err: "+err));
```

Wrapping every function body in a try-catch block is not an option as an inner `.catch(...)` is already more elegant.

The throwing of `Error` is a minimal example, of course, assume it occurs by accident and that the promise returned by `promise2` is expected to do something useful and has a bug.

I'm looking for a principle which allows deeper nesting, e.g. with a `promise2` which returns a `promise3` which then accidentally might throw an error like `promise2` does now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `promise2` already returns a Promise, so there's no need for explicit construction of a Promise *again*. Instead, just chain off of the `promise2`, and if the value it resolves to is not OK, throw an error instead of calling `reject`. (Similarly, instead of calling `resolve`, `return` the expression you want the outer Promise to resolve to)

```js
function promise1() {
  return promise2().then(promise2Result => {
      if (promise2Result !== "") {
        return "The value is " + promise2Result;
      } else {
        throw new Error("promise2.then error");
      }
    })
}

function promise2() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    throw new Error("promise2 error");
  });
}

promise1()
  .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```